# jquery to node : POST seen as GET

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating an android mobile application with Phonegap, so i decided to use jQuery mobile with it. The server side is to be handled by a node.js application.

In client side, I make javascript send a POST request:

```
function validate() {
            //alert($('#username').val());
            var uname = $('#username').val() ;
            var pword = $('#password').val() ;
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonpCallback: "responding",
                url : "http://localhost:8888/authenticate",
                data :  { username: uname , password : pword },
                success : function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error, status = " + textStatus + ", " + "error thrown: " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
```

and in server side, node gets it using

```
function authenticate(request, response) {
console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
console.log(request);
response.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type" : "text/plain"
});
response.write('responding(\'{"message": "Dummy Reply!"}\')');
response.end();
```

}

When I tied console.log(request) as you can see, in the console, along with a lot of stuff, i got this..

> url: '/authenticate?callback=responding&username=foo&password=bar&_=1388071403212',
>     method: 'GET',

How on earth did a POST method became a GET method when it came to the server??

Also can you tell me how to get the parameters in a POST request at the node side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `POST` a `JSONP` request.

```
type : "POST",
dataType: "jsonp",
```

`JSONP` requests are almost always `GET` (jQuery simply appends a `<script>`) tag to the DOM) (there may be some exception for same-domain requests)

Comment: but the dataType curresponds to response isnt it?

Comment: @JamsheedKamarudeen I suggest reading exactly what it does at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Also, read the jQuery source code to see more details.

Comment: Since it is not a same origin , I have no other option than to use a jsonp isnt it?